Surface-fitting
I have grabbed a bunch of points in 3d that define a relatively simple 3d surface (three of them):



I've been trying to figure out how to come up with a function for each (using curve_fit from scipy), but I'm probably doing something wrong -- I thought that going with something like a quadratic function would be enough for this:
def f(X, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    x, y = X
    return a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + f*x*y
    
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, (mirek, brightness), normal)
print(popt)

But the resulting coefficients have a huge error that doesn't come anywhere close to approximating the original surface.
Could anyone please point me to the right direction? I'm capable to learn, but this (reversing a math function out of observed behavior) is a completely new thing for me.
Also, I mostly have generic opensource tools at my disposal (ruby, python, gnuplot, etc), so telling me that there's a Mathematica/Matlab package would not help much...

You could try tensor product splines. In fact the visualization that you have is achieved through those. The question is how low you can get the resolution of said tensor product splines. The fitting for those is a linear least squares problem.

@lightxbulb thanks, I'll check it out, there's scipy.interpolate.NdBSpline ...

I'm going to briefly answer my own question.
As suggested in the comments, I tried higher order functions, then PySR, and it didn't work well for me.
In the end, I decided to divide-and-conquer:

Approximate the brightness
Approximate the color temperature curves for the individual PWM channels

For the first, I noticed that if I project the normal channel to 2d, with one curve per brightness:

The individual curves look very similar, as if scaled. And that is indeed the case.
Using:
brightness = np.array(data["brightness"])
normal = np.array(data["normal"])

def f(X, a, b, c):
    x = X
    return (a + b*x + c*x**2)

def pretty_print(name, popt, pcov, x_data, y_data):
    print(name + ":")
    print('popt:', popt)
    print('pcov:', pcov)
    perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
    print('perr:', perr)
    y_pred = f((x_data), *popt)
    mse = np.mean((y_data - y_pred)**2)
    print("mse:", mse)
    print()

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, (brightness), normal)
pretty_print('normal', popt, pcov, (brightness), normal)

I got reasonable fit:
normal:
popt: [ 9.99462593e-01 -3.40382133e-04  9.90325710e-03]
pcov: [[ 1.03065521e-05 -4.85098868e-07  4.14057014e-09]
 [-4.85098868e-07  3.92993010e-08 -3.84299001e-10]
 [ 4.14057014e-09 -3.84299001e-10  3.96309146e-12]]
perr: [3.21038193e-03 1.98240513e-04 1.99075148e-06]
mse: 8.65420496797531e-05

Which when overlaid with collected data points fits rather well:

Then I used similar approach, only higher order function ((a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3 + e*x**4 + f*x**5)) to figure out the color temperature curves.
The one additional trick was to remove the points of saturation, and for the curve depicted above to break it apart to two pieces -- one per "slope".
Result of the lin regression is also decent fit:

When combined, the error is actually pretty low (I think):




From the graphics of your data, I doubt that quadratic functions would be enough. You could try with higher-order polynomials and compare the results for some of them.
An alternative approach would be to use symbolic regression. There is a Python package called PySR that is somewhat easy to use.

OK, I briefly tried 5-degree polynomial, and that helped to get the error down some. I'll experiment further. Also, thanks for the link to the symbolic regression, I'll check it out...

Since your data appears to be on a grid, the right approach is to use that grid to define the interpolating function -- for example using piecewise bilinear polynomials as in the finite element method.

I would very much like to avoid using lookup tables and interpolation, since there's definitely some simple generating function for these (PWM controller for lights). But yes, worst case, I'd do that...

Then project onto a coarser mesh. That too should be easy enough with gridded data.

In the end, divide and conquer did the trick: https://wejn.org/2024/12/hue-engine-reversing-the-functions/ I think the projection onto a mesh would be rather problematic (for me).
